# Download Files into a certain path in the internal Storage { C# Xamarin }

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-download-manager

currently I am curious how to download files on your android device and save the file to a certain path on the INTERNAL STORAGE. My result I want to get at the end is: If the User click on a button it start to download and replace the file in the path that is defined.

Appreciate any help!

With my current code i tried to modify it directly, but had no success...

Wish y´all a Great Day & thanks for reading!

*Frost

```
            Renegade = new Command(async () =>
            {

                string pak5 = "";

                Stream stream1 = File.OpenRead(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "Android/data/com.epicgames.fortnite/files/InstalledBundles/FortniteBR/FortniteGame/Content/Paks/pakchunk10_s5-Android_ASTCClient.ucas");

                

                /*using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(pak5, true))
                {
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow);
                }

                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(pak5))
                {
                    string content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(content);
                }*/

                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream1);
                string pakspath = reader.ReadToEnd();

                //80000000
                //80000000

                //System.IO.File.Delete("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.epicgames.fortnite/files/InstalledBundles/FortniteBR/FortniteGame/Content/Paks/pakchunk10_s5-Android_ASTCClient.ucas ");

                //Utilities.Convert(Body, Body1, pakspath, 80000000);
                //Utilities.Convert(Mat, Mat1, pakspath, 8981062);

                ReplaceBytes(pakspath, 8981045, S1);
                ReplaceBytes(pakspath, 8981045, S2);
                ReplaceBytes(pakspath, 80782548, S3);
                ReplaceBytes(pakspath, 80782548, S4);
                ReplaceBytes(pakspath, 80782571, S5);
                ReplaceBytes(pakspath, 80782571, S6);



            });
```

Comment: because the current code has nothing to do with what i planned. Like I said my current code is about how to modify it directly and not download the modified file and replace it. It has nothing to do with the direct question, but if you have some knowledge and could help me out with a method on how to access files in the internal storage?

Comment: @Jason btw I added the Code now in my question if you would be able to take a look at it - appreciate you read it :)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+android+download+file+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: You are not even mentioning the path you try to use. Vague post.

Comment: @blackapps read the code and you see the exact path? Also, it isn't really needed, since it´s just about how to access in general the internal storage and read / write on it...

Comment: Yes... you decide which info we need. Great!

Comment: @blackapps There is literally everything you need to reply to this question and if you want to help me out and need anything i am grateful to provide these informations. But you dont asked for it and just said vague post?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xamarin forms then ,Here is my solution.Make a class like this on your
Android project.

```
public class DroidFileHelper 
    {
        
        public string GetLocalFilePath(string filename)
        {
            string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            return Path.Combine(path, filename);
        }

        public async Task SaveFileToDefaultLocation(string fileName, byte[] bytes, bool showFile = false)
        {
            Context currentContext = Android.App.Application.Context;
            string directory = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
            if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
            }
            string file = Path.Combine(directory, fileName);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(file, bytes);

            //If you want to open up the file after download the use below code
            if (showFile)
            {
               
                if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.N)
                {

                    string externalStorageState = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageState;
                    var externalPath = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path + "/" + global::Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads + "/" + fileName;
                    File.WriteAllBytes(externalPath, bytes);

                    Java.IO.File files = new Java.IO.File(externalPath);
                    files.SetReadable(true);

                    string application = "application/pdf";
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
                    Android.Net.Uri uri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(currentContext, "com.companyname.appname.provider", files);
                    intent.SetDataAndType(uri, application);
                    intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
                    Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
                    promptInstall.SetDataAndType(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(file)), "application/pdf");
                    promptInstall.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                    Forms.Context.StartActivity(promptInstall);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

after that call it like from your xamarin form.

```
Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>().SaveFileToDefaultLocation(oFile.FileName, oFile.FileInBytes, true);
```

It will save your file to Downloads because we set the path as `Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads` in our droid helper class

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I added that class and it worked fine, but since I am new to Xamarin´; What do you mean with calling it in my form? I dont know if I did it right - I added it in the command section in the button from my main xamarin file where the buttons are. Sorry for this dumb question

Comment: Yes you are right .you have to add Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>().SaveFileToDefaultLocation(oFile.FileName, oFile.FileInBytes, true); from your command of button